# How to make intangible text in emacs to be completely removed by deletion commands?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like the whole intangible text to be deleted by `delete-char` and `backward-delete-char`. Any easy way?

```
(put-text-property (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol) 'intangible t)
```

`kill-word` and `backward-kill-word` will delete the intangible text, and I'd like the `*-char` commands to do the same.

In the user interface I am building, some critical text is invisible and intangible. So when user presses <kbd>DEL</kbd> (<kbd>C-d</kbd>) just after (before) the hidden, intangible text, the whole text should disappear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an Emacs without any initialization files, and the `(put-text...` code you provided, I can delete characters at the beginning of the line with <kbd>M-x delete-char</kbd> (<kbd>C-d</kbd>), and delete characters at the end of the line with <kbd>M-x backward-delete-char</kbd> (<kbd>DEL</kbd> (well, that's really `delete-backward-char`)).

*Edited upon clarification of question*:

These two pieces of advice will delete the entire intangible region:

```
(defadvice delete-char (around delete-char-intangible activate)
  "when about to delete a char that's intangible, delete the whole region
Only do this when #chars is 1"
  (if (and (= (ad-get-arg 0) 1)
           (get-text-property (point) 'intangible))
      (kill-region (point) (save-excursion (forward-char 1) (point)))
    ad-do-it))

(defadvice delete-backward-char (around delete-backward-char-intangible activate)
  "when about to delete a char that's intangible, delete the whole region
Only do this interactively and when #chars is 1"
  (if (and (= (ad-get-arg 0) 1) (> (point) (point-min))
           (get-text-property (- (point) 1) 'intangible))
      (kill-region (point) (save-excursion (backward-char 1) (point)))
    ad-do-it))
```

The advice checks to ensure that the command is being called with an argument of 1, and only then will delete the entire intangible region, otherwise it behaves as normal.

Comment: Sorry for not being very precise. I would like the deletion commands to delete the whole intangible text not only
part of it. In the user interface I am building,  some critical text is invisible and intangible. So when user
presses DEL (C-d) just after (before) the hidden, intangible text the whole text should disappear.

Thanks.